# Open datepicker on datetextfield click

Tags: java, wicket

Is it possible to open/ popup wicket datepicker by datetextfield onclick? Or is there any other way to do that. I am using wicket 1.3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to dig into DateTextfield to bind a `onfocus` or `onclick` javascript event on the generated input field which triggers the opening.

I don't have my IDE right now to point you to the exact piece of code but I can have a look later if you want...

Comment: By firing my IDE I saw `DatePicker#setShowOnFieldClick(boolean)` which  seems to do what you want to but as far as I can see it is not in 1.3.6. You've got two way of doing it, either you backport this behavior from Wicket 1.4.x (look at DatePicker.js, wicket-date.js and DatePicker.java) or you trigger the event. Depending of the framework you use it would be like this (I don't know much of YUI so it is in JQuery) : `$('#'+calDomId+'Icon').click();`

Comment: Figured out using YUI : `YAHOO.wicket.${textFieldId}DpJs.show()` seems to do the trick, just replace `${textFieldId}` with the markup id of your `DateTextField`...

Comment: @Cedric Gatay thanks. But I am unable to do that. I tried `YAHOO.wicket.${textFieldId}DpJs.show()` but no luck. And also download wicket 1.4.17 's code for datepicker, modify and use it and again no luck. :(

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid I can't help you more, the hack is not that difficult, keep on trying...

Comment: @Cedric Gatay hi, I made it. At first I integrate YUI 2 calendar with wicket in custom way and configured such a way that the calendar poup will open on textfield click. But I couldn't attach AjaxEvent with that textfield. Then I collect wicket-datetime 1.4.17 source code and modify it for wicket 1.3.6 and then integrate it with my source code. Fortunately it's working. Thanks for your suggestion, I didn't know about the DatePicker#setShowOnFieldClick(). Also I set DatePicker#enableMonthYearSelection to true, by default it is false, also this method can be overloaded. :) Thanks and Regards.